# Javascript slideshow library with ability to add options to download, email image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow

I am working on a digital asset management product where users can upload images (among other types) and do some operations like transmit, download, transform, share etc. We are working to add an "embed" option for a set of selected images where the embed will be in a form of slideshow. I am looking for a javascript/jquery library that will help me create a slideshow with following options:

1. When slideshow is paused, there should be some way to identify current image.
2. Custom height, width.
3. Ability to accommodate images of different dimensions.
4. Ability to add some caption with the images.
5. Customizable navigation controls.
6. Preferably free.

With #1, what we want to do is user should be able to pause the slideshow and then select to download/transmit the image. Obviously I need to know which image is the current one.

I have seen many resources saying "25 best jquery slideshow libraries" etc. but there are just too many options out there. I am going through those one by one but so far I haven't found one which will match my requirements; #1 above being the most important.

If anyone has come across similar situation, your feedback is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: At the moment Galleria (http://galleria.io/) seems to fit the bill. Working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was done using a library called Galleria. Its API is quite rich and provides methods like GetData (returns details of current image in slideshow), GetIndex (returns index of current image). The input data can be specified as HTML or JSON which is a big plus since in a JSON object we can fill extra details we might need on client side. Everything that is a part of JSON object is returned by GetData. Now once I identify current image, it's easy to link to other options that I wanted.

http://galleria.io/docs/1.2/api/methods/